# What does `rec` mean in Scheme 84

Tags: reflection, syntax, scheme

I was reading Friedman and Wand's ["Reification: Reflection Without Metaphysics"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/800055.802051) and it uses the following `rec` syntax which I do not know:

```
(define <simple>                            
  (lambda (fun)
    (lambda (e r k)
      ((rec loop ; <--- What is rec here?
            (lambda (e k)
              (if (null? e) (k nil)
                ((denotation (first
                               e))
                 r
                 (lambda (v)
                   (loop
                     (rest e)
                     (lambda (w)
                       (k (cons v w)))))))))
       (lambda (v*) (fun v* k))))))
```

The paper says they use Scheme 84, but I couldn't find that reference manual on schemers.org (or on google for that matter). Could someone please explain this `rec` syntax? A few simple examples that use `rec` would be appreciated as well.

Comment: it is like `letrec*`.  but you will understand the semantics just by keeping reading.

Comment: See [SRFI-31](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html), which has some relevant history and rationale.

Answer (score 2):

Found what it means on Chez Scheme reference [here](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/binding.html#./binding:s17). It is a macro that expands as follows:

```
(define-syntax rec
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ x e) (letrec ((x e)) x)]))
```

For example,

```
(rec last-of (lambda (l)
               (cond
                 [(null? l) (error "List too small")]
                 [(= (length l) 1) (car l)]
                 [else (last-of (cdr l))])))
```

would return the procedure for finding the last element of a list.